# What is this Bible with red printing?

Tags: bible, esv

[image: Image of passage printed in red]

I want to buy this Bible, does anyone know what the title of this version of the Bible is, or know any versions which has highlighted text? Only ESV. Thank you.

Comment: If you type that exact text in a search engine you'll probably find the correct version. As for the actual title of the published book, no idea

Comment: At the following website you will see almost every translation of the Bible, and see exactly what each looks like before you buy. I also has prices and explanations. http://biblegateway.christianbook.com/page/bibles/1419322411?navcocat=biblegateway_Bibles

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the benefits of a red letter edition Bible?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-red-letter-edition-bible)

Comment: I'm sorry you seem to be dissatisfied with your experience here, but defacing the site be removing content and replacing it with junk is not allowed. If you would like to be disassociated from the content you can see [how to remove your account](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) in our help pages, but one you post the content here belongs to the community and they have a right to keep it clean and formatted according to site standards.

Answer (score 8):

Normally these bibles are called ***red-letter*** or ***Dominical words*** bibles (*Dominical* meaning "of the Lord" — it's the words of Jesus which are printed in red).

There used to be an [ESV red-letter bible](http://www.crossway.org/bibles/esv-classic-reference-bible-genuine-lea-1033-gltr/) but it's out of print. I can't find whether they currently print a red-letter version, but there are some of that leather-bound red-letter edition [available via Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/1581343205/ref=tmm_hrd_used_olp_0?ie=UTF8&condition=used&qid=1399112314&sr=8-1) at the moment.

Two-colour printing is far more expensive than single-colour, so it tends to go with high-end features like leather binding. The end result is sold in such low volumes that it becomes uneconomical to maintain and even second-hand prices remain quite high.

The image you provided is of the [New King James Version](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2016&version=NKJV) which obviously also had printed red-letter editions. There's an imitation-leather NKJV edition [available quite cheaply](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Deluxe-Bible-Letter-Imitation-Leather/dp/1433604671) at the moment.

Comment: There are some online red-letter versions as well.

Comment: The imitation leather version is cheap (I bought one for less that two dollars second hand, very attractive, nicely packed in a box, and it is now my first choice for quick searches as it is well organized and handles well. A good buy if that is what the picture is.

Comment: @gideonmarx You seem ideally well-equipped to see if the end of John 16 matches!

Comment: Matthew 16. But I see what you mean. Wonder what Bible this is.