# In which scriptures are Jesus' Words?

Tags: words-of-jesus

I'm highlighting Jesus Words in red colour in new version of Bible.
I would like to know which scriptures have Jesus' Words.
As far as I know, Mat, Mark, Luke, John have Jesus' Words, so I have to highlighting the Words in these scriptures. Are there still scriptures left to highlight for Jesus's Words?

Comment: Forgive me if this is an insensitive question, but since Pastor Vicy died on 9 September 2019, may I enquire who you are?  A Pastor would know the answer to this question so I can only assume this is not your name.  If you are a close relative, please accept my heartfelt sympathy.

Comment: @Lesley  check out his profile info

Comment: @Kris It's the information in the profile that led me to ask my question.

Comment: I see.    Iguess this user is trying to honor the memory in some way?

Comment: I suspect Lesley's answer is your best choice. Of course, you should be aware there is no 'canonical' list of passages spoken by Jesus; John 3 is an example where it is disputed. You might want to mark passages in your bible as you recognize them as Jesus' direct words, or you might want a computerized list of all "red" words, which I could probably help you find.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than attempt to highlight all of Jesus' words in the four Gospels, you would benefit from buying a "Red Letter" Bible which has Jesus' words already printed in red.  My English Standard Version Study Bible is a good example of this.

The book of Acts also has Jesus' spoken words printed in red but they appear only in chapters 1, 9, 22, 23, and 26.

The book of Revelation also has Jesus' spoken words printed in red in chapter 1 to 4, 16, and 22.

The accepted answer to this question may be helpful: [What are the benefits of a red letter edition Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-red-letter-edition-bible?rq=1)

I strongly advise you not to deface your Bible with red highlighter but buy a New Testament where it has been done professionally and is easy to read.

Comment: Do not forget Acts 20:35, where Paul quotes Jesus: In everything I did, I showed you that by this kind of hard work we must help the weak, remembering the words the Lord Jesus himself said: 'It is more blessed to give than to receive.' "

Comment: @Paul Chernoch Well spotted! And then there is Acts 23:11 when the Lord Jesus spoke to Paul to encourage him (see Acts19:21).

Answer (score 2):

The gospels directly record what Jesus said.  The entire Bible indirectly records what Jesus said as Jesus and the Father are One.

> 2 Peter 1:20 But know this first of all, that no prophecy of Scripture is a
>   matter of one’s own interpretation, 21 for no prophecy was ever made
>   by an act of human will, but men moved by the Holy Spirit spoke from
>   God.
>
> Acts 20:28 Be on guard for yourselves and for all the flock, among
>   which the Holy Spirit has made you overseers, to shepherd the church
>   of God which He purchased with His own blood.

Comment: What you say is entirely true but the question is clearly wanting help with identifying Jesus' SPOKEN words, while he was on earth. This means that a helpful answer would mention the risen Christ's conversation with John as recorded in the book of Revelation. There are other N.T. letters where the apostles quote Jesus' words, so they could help answer the question. As your answer stands, it does not answer the actual question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Anne and great catch on the Revelation passage.  From my years of experience people all too often place a premium the red letters devaluing the rest of the scriptures and at times build their entire doctrine off of the gospels.  This is why I added the indirect qualifier.

Comment: That is so true, Lionsden, and I appreciate the worth of making that indirect qualifier. By the way, I have not down-voted you, but have up-voted you.

Comment: Much appreciated.  Thank you.